# Append value to variable during loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to loop through a text file found during a wildcard search and append each line as its own portion of a string.

My file has the two lines:

```
Load.SQL.Sample.Basic.Data
Script.Calc.Sample.Basic.AggAll
```

I want to loop through them and aggregate them into one variable. At each step I want it to echo what's in the variable:

```
Load.Sql.Sample.Basic.Data
Load.Sql.Sample.Basic.Data Script.Calc.Sample.Basic.AggAll
```

This script just replicates the input file:

```
set JOBLIST=
FOR %%i in (*.Job.txt) DO (
    FOR /F %%a in (%%i) DO (
        SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
        set JOBLIST=!JOBLIST! %%a
        echo !JOBLIST!>>Test.txt
        ENDLOCAL
    )
)
```

This is the output (each line has a leading space):

```
 Load.SQL.Sample.Basic.Data
 Script.Calc.Sample.Basic.AggAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the delayed expansion in the wrong place:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i in (*.Job.txt) DO (
    FOR /F %%a in (%%i) DO (
        set JOBLIST=!JOBLIST! %%a
        echo !JOBLIST!>>Test.txt        
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```